# Show that if a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable with differentiable inverse then $m = n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

So far I have:

$\boldsymbol{f^{-1}} \circ \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a}) = \boldsymbol{a}
\implies [\boldsymbol{D}(\boldsymbol{f^{-1}}(\boldsymbol{a}) \circ \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a}))] = I_n
\implies [\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{f^{-1}}(\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a}))][\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a})] = I_n $ by the chain rule.

Interpreting $[\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{f^{-1}}(\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a}))]$ as the matrix composed of row-reduction operations, $[\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a})]$ row-reduces to $I_n$. Now $[\boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{a})]$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, therefore we have $m \le n$: Is this convincing? How do I make it rigorous?

This looks like a similar question to [Existence of an inverse to differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257599/the-existence-of-an-inverse-to-a-differentiable-function)

Comment: I don't know very well but I think if we just think about the $f\circ{g}=id_{\mathbb R^n}, g\circ{f}=id_{\mathbb R^m}$ and $D(f)D(g)=I_n, D(g)D(f)=I_m$, then we can not prove $m=n$. And we need some algebraic topology or differential topology method to prove. @satishb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function $f$, which is differentiable, bijective and has a differentiable inverse, is called a diffeomorphism.

**Claim:** If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a diffeomorphism, then $Df(x)$ is bijective for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

*Proof*:
Let us consider $f^{-1}\cdot f(x)=x$ and $f\cdot f^{-1}(x)=x$.

Deriving the first equation gives you

$$Df^{-1}(f(x))Df(x)=I_n$$

and the second equation gives

$$Df(f^{-1}(y))Df^{-1}(y)=I_m$$

Setting $y=f(x)$, we see that the second equation becomes

$$Df(x)Df^{-1}(f(x))=I_m$$

But this just means that $Df(x)$ is an invertible matrix with inverse $Df(x)^{-1}=Df^{-1}(f(x))$.
$\square$

Can a $m\times n$ matrix be invertible if $m\not=n$?

No, therefore $f$ being a diffeomorphism implies $m=n$.

**Note**: This also applies to diffeomorphisms $f:U\rightarrow V$ where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $V\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ open (with the same proof, being differentiable is a local property). The result is called *invariance of dimension/invariance of domain*.

For merely *continuous* maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ which are bijective and have a continuous inverse (called homeomorphisms), this result also holds true, but requires more machinery (using singular homology it is trivial, but one can also prove it in an "elementary" way using Brouwer's fixed point theorem).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to show is the following: Assume that $m>n$, and $I_m :\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ the identity map. ($I_m$ is also the identity $m\times m$ matrix). Then for $a\in\mathbb R^μ$
$$
I_m=f\circ f^{-1}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad I_m=DI_m =Df\big(f^{-1}(a)\big) Df^{-1}(a).
$$
But $Df\big(f^{-1}(a)\big)$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and its rank is at most $n$, while $Df^{-1}(a)$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, and its rank is also at most $n$. Hence their product has also rank at most $n$, which  contradict the fact that their product is the $m\times m$ identity matrix, with rank $m>n$.

Comment: I do not agree with $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $I_m = f \circ f^{-1}$. Either $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $I_m = f \circ f^{-1}$, or $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $I_n = f^{-1} \circ f$. I looked further in the textbook where I got this problem from and rank is defined later, and the rest  of your proof is convincing. The only hint given is to use the fact that if $A$ row-reduces to $I$ then $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has a solution for every $\vec{b}$.

Comment: @satishb: You are right!